# Detecting touch events in Android notification bar

Tags: android, touch-event, ime

I am writing a custom InputMethod for Android tablets (Honeycomb). I noticed that the default keyboard implementation detects touch events on the notification area beneath the spacebar (and other keys) and activates the closest key. I would like to implement similar functionality. However, my InputMethod (which uses a custom view) simply is hidden when you touch the notification area. How do I detect and handle touch events on the notification area instead of allowing them to hide my InputMethod?